# How many strings of length $n$ from the digits $0$ to $9$ contain $131$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve this problem by dividing the string into two strings one with length $k$ and ends with $13$ and the other string with length $n-k$ and start with $1$ taking into accont that $k$ may change $n+1$ once and that the strings must be on the same order ( start with string of length $k$ )...

But I miss something I don't know.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the alphabet?  Just the $10$ digits?  Something else?  In any case, I expect it is easier to count the strings that do not contain $131$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @lulu I tried to do that but I have to omit a lot of cases which is hard

Comment: @José Carlos Santos sorry I'll do better in my next question

Comment: While you are at it, @neloverAR, do better by writing  "I" instead of writing "i," the square root of -1.

Answer (score 1):

**This might help but it looks a long-winded method.**

Recurrence relations can be set up for the number of strings **not** containing $131$. 
For such strings, let $S(n)$ count those starting with a $1$ and let $N(n)$ count the others.

For $N(n)$, there are $9$ possible initial digits and then $N(n-1)+S(n-1)$ choices for the remaining digits. So $$N(n)=9(N(n-1)+S(n-1)).$$

The strings in $S(n)$ may start $11$. There are $S(n-1)$ of these.

They may start $13$. There are $N(n-2)$ of these.

Otherwise, there are $8$ possibilities for the second digit and $N(n-2)+S(n-2)$ choices for the remaining digits. Then $S(n)=S(n-1)+N(n-2)+8(N(n-2)+S(n-2)).$
$$S(n)=S(n-1)+9N(n-2)+S(n-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Counting the strings that contain $131$ is a somewhat non-trivial endeavour because the substring $131$ can occur more than once and different occurrences may or may not overlap. It can be done using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

To count the strings that contain $131$, we have $n-2$ conditions, one for each possible position that might contain $131$. If $k\gt0$ particular conditions are fulfilled, they can overlap in $0\le j\le k-1$ places, thus forming $k-j$ blocks and determining $3k-j$ letters. The $k-j$ blocks and the $n-(3k-j)$ remaining letters can be permuted in $\binom{n-(3k-j)+k-j}{k-j}=\binom{n-2k}{k-j}$ ways, and the remaining letters can take $10^{n-(3k-j)}$ different values, so by inclusion–exclusion the total number of strings of length $n$ containing $131$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-2k}{k-j}10^{n-(3k-j)}\;.
\end{eqnarray}